# How to create space at the bottom of a the 1st page only

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

How should I add space at the bottom of a particular page? I want to create a space at bottom of 1st page and it should not followed for other pages. Suppose I want the last four line to go to the next page, as this will create a space for me. From bottom of a page I want page to break but it should not create paragraph.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... Maybe are looking for `\newpage`?

Comment: Maybe using `\vfill` ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "a smooth break" - do you want the page contents to be vertically centred (which I think is @MarioS.E.'s suggestion)?

Comment: If you want Tex to automatically avoid breaking paragraphs, `\raggedbottom` will achieve this without you having to specify which paragraph to stop at.  It is possible to ensure this happens just for one page or just for the first page of each chapter, say.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `\enlargethispage{-4\baselineskip}` somewhere within the page you want to adjust.  this will shorten just this one page by the number of lines you specify (assuming that the lines are spaced evenly) -- "enlarge" can be negative as well as positive.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are trying to do... for a page break at any point you desire, simply add `\newpage` where you want the break to occur.

This will leave a "blank space" at the bottom of your page (where you insert the break).